# Delete record based on condition in parent table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables defined in my database:

```
moderator (id, name)

parent_object (id, moderator_id, parent_name)

child_object (id, parent_id, child_name, quantity)
```

I want to delete a child object based on the ID. I currently have something like this which works:

```
delete from child_object where id = 3;
```

However, there is a security hole because this allows any moderator to update any child object that they do not own. If the moderator_id is 2, how can I delete this record so that it will only delete it if the moderator_id of the parent_object is 2?

Comment: are you using any server side language to connect to the database? This security check is usually implemented on the server side.

Comment: @Silencer310 I am using PHP (PDO). I do not see how it can be implemented with server side unless I make more than one request to the database server.

Comment: you want to prevent a moderator to update a child other than itself, doesn't that mean you know the moderator before running the query, and also the moderator's id?

Comment: Yes, you do know the moderator id, but you do not know whether that moderator owns the parent object of the child object they want to delete.

Comment: right, that would require more than 1 request.

Comment: Exactly, and if you can do it in one request, it is much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE c.* FROM child_object c 
    INNER JOIN parent_object p ON c.parent_id = p.id  
WHERE c.id = 3 AND p.moderator_id = 2
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7290b5/1/0